# How do I initialize a Vec from multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, rust, parallel-processing, atomic

I have code that generates a CSR sparse matrix by reading multiple parquet files in parallel, preprocessing the data, then finally acquiring a mutex to sequentially write into the sparse array data structure. This is roughly the pseudocode for each thread:

```
read parquet data
get list of nonzero values
acquire mutex
append nonzero values to sparse array (basically memcpy)
release mutex
repeat
```

The speed of the code doesn't increase with more CPUs, so I suspect the mutex contention is a bottleneck. So I would like to try replacing the mutex with an atomic "offset" variable into the sparse array, so that I can do something like this:

```rust
fn push(&self, rhs: &Self, offset: &AtomicU64) -> MyResult<()> {
    let old = offset.fetch_add(rhs.data.0.len() + (1 << 32), Ordering::SeqCst);
    let (nnz, m) = (old & 0xffffffff, old >> 32);
    let indptr = nnz.try_into()? + rhs.data.0.len().try_into()?;
    let range = nnz..nnz + rhs.data.0.len();

    self.data[range].copy_from_slice(&rhs.data.0);
    self.indices[range].copy_from_slice(&rhs.indices.0);
    self.indptr[m] = indptr;
    self.y[m] = rhs.y.0[0];

    Ok(())
}
```

I.e. I want each thread to first atomically update the pointer into the sparse array, then write into the preceding data. Problem is, the data is an immutable reference `&` (in order to pass it to each thread), and I need a mutable reference `&mut` (in order to update it). Reading similar questions and Rust documentation it seems you can't do this simple task like you would in C, but no alternative is provided, which is quite irritating.

Comment: I only really read the title. But does this boil down to, e.g. whether it's possible to assign to `0..9` in one thread, then `10..19` in a second thread, etc?

Comment: Not quite, because the range is dynamic, i.e. each thread is reading in dynamic arrays of data and basically I want to concatenate them.

Comment: Do you know the final size of the array ahead of time? If you don't, this gets really tricky because whenever you try to grow the array, it may need to be reallocated at a different location. A linked list would be a better fit but probably have bad performance. Would you consider at least waiting until all the data is processed and ready to be concatenated, so you can compute the final length?

Comment: I know the final length of the entire array, i.e. the number of nonzero elements in the sparse matrix, so reallocation isn't a problem. However I don't know how many nonzero elements are in each row of data that I'm reading from parallel threads.

Comment: I didn't see any primitives that get you all the way there, but one nice thing about Rust is that if a primitive doesn't exist, you can build one yourself. This is a [first cut](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a29eabfb478557a24a0bcf450930053f) at using `unsafe` to put together something that I think would work for your case. Everything in `mod vec_filler` could be put into its own file (or, potentially, its own crate). There are definitely ways to use atomics instead of that mutex, but it should reduce contention as-is.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers my question.